# Combine more than one Style in a map

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

Here is what I'm trying to achieve: I want to combine more than one Style (a map built by the user in the Mapbox Studio) in a single map.

Let's say we have a Style with some base layers and tilesets, and another Style with just one tileset but with colors and other styling configuration and I want to dynamically combine them in my map.

**What I have tried**

1. I add the first Style with `setStyle`
2. Make a request to the Styles API and get the second Style json
3. Iterate over the sources of the second Style and add them to the map using `addSource` (renaming to avoid conflict)
4. Iterate over the layers of the second Style and add them to the map usgin `addLayer`

It pretty much worked, I only got errors with layers that use a "text-field" and require the style to have a "glyphs" attribute.

I then tried do dynamically change the "glyphs" attribute of the map Style but it didn't work. The error persists.

`Error: "layers.state-label.layout.text-field: use of "text-field" requires a style "glyphs" property"`

**Why don't I add tilesets instead?**

Because I want to get the all the layout options present in the Style.

**Why didn't I open an issue about how to change the glyphs dynamically?**

Alhtough this is the concrete problem I'm facing right now I was willing to get feedback on the general approach.

Is it something doable? Should I consider combining more than one style in the map a good idea? Is there a better way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Leo,,

Answer (score 0):

Your approach sounds generally fine, with a couple of major caveats, which you have discovered:

1. A style can only have a single font glyph
2. A style can only have a single icon sprite

If both are hosted under the same user account on Studio, I think it might work, at least for fonts. But judging from your error, that's not the case.

So what can you do? You will have to pick the font glyph from one style, then update every layer in the other style to use a font present in that style. I think that would be hard to do in the general case (I don't know how to find out what fonts are present in a glyph), so the safest option might be to create a new font glyph and remap every font to it.

FWIW, this general issue is already tracked here: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/4225

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for your reply. Can you please elaborate on how to set the glyphs style property after the map is already loaded? I want to fix the problem for combining styles from the same account, that`s enough for now.

But when I use setStyle with an url to a Style that dont have a glyphs url set, I did not manage to add this property later on the script.

Comment: You would have to modify it in the style JSON (just modifying the top `glyphs` property), then call `setStyle()`